# Sitefinity - Get Sub Library Name List Template

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-feather

So I'm making a list template for Sitefinity's document widget. The documents are in a library that is located in another library and I want to display that sub library name at the top of the list. The thing is I cant get that sub library name I can only get the parents name. This will make more sense id you see the screenshots. I would like to have "Child Library" as the title, but can't figure it out.

```
<ul class="simpleZebraList @Model.CssClass">
    @if (Model.Items.Count() > 0)
    {
        var firstItem = Model.Items.First();
        <h4>@firstItem.Fields.Parent.Title</h4>
    }

    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {

    <li>
        <div class="title">@item.Fields.Title</div>
        <div class="link">
            <a class="cta" href="@item.Fields.MediaUrl" target="_blank">Download</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    }

@if (Model.ShowPager)
{
    @Html.Action("Index", "ContentPager", new
    {
        currentPage = Model.CurrentPage,
        totalPagesCount = Model.TotalPagesCount.Value,
        redirectUrlTemplate = ViewBag.RedirectPageUrlTemplate
    })
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

cast firstItem.DataItem to Document and then use FolderId property to get the Id of the folder (child library). Then use LibrariesManager to get the folder by that Id and you should be able to get its name.